# Cannot not connect to database server within docker-compose (php and MariaDB)

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I've built a docker-compose file that creates 2 services (PHP and MariaDB). Somehow I cannot connect to the database from the PHP service: Within the PHP service, a Laravel-app is running.

The error message (redirect is a table within the database):

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `redirects`)

All env-variables should be correct.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  faaren_backend:
    image: php:alpine
    container_name: FAA-Backend
    volumes:
      - "./:/faaren_backend"
    working_dir: /faaren_backend
    command: "php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    build:
      context: docker/php
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile

  faaren_database:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: FAA-Database
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
    volumes:
    - "faa-db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data"

volumes:
  faa-db-data: {}
```

My dev.Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libzip-dev \
         && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pecl install imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-enable imagick

RUN apt-get install $PHPIZE_DEPS && \
    pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql pcntl

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

VOLUME /faaren_backend
```

And finally my .env-file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=faaren_backend
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=faaren_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Mostly I've followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/swlh/laravel-with-docker-compose-de2190569084

Comment: Did you try taking the `ports` value for the db out of quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change your docker database host:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=faaren_database <-- edit
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=faaren_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

And in docker-compose.yml faaren_backend section add:

```
depends_on:
  - faaren_database
```

Hope it's help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you deal with a race condition. You need to use `depends_on` directive to control startup order and use *wait* script to make sure that service ready to accept connections:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  faaren_backend:
    image: php:alpine
    container_name: FAA-Backend
    volumes:
      - "./:/faaren_backend"
    working_dir: /faaren_backend
    command: entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - faaren_database
    build:
      context: docker/php
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile

  faaren_database:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: FAA-Database
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - "faa-db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data"

volumes:
  faa-db-data: {}
```

There are a bunch of ways to check service availability, sometimes [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) can be really handy. In the example below used `netcat`(you need to install it into the container).

Also, it'a good idea to put a script into a separated file:

*entrypoint.sh*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
until nc -w 1 -z faaren_database 3306; do
  >&2 echo "Mysql is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done
sleep 10
>&2 echo "Mysql is up - executing command"

php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

**UPDATE**: Specify correct `DB_HOST` how Dmitry suggested as well.